# Syntax Error in query expression ? how to solve that

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to insert value from select statement and i got error

> Syntax error in query expression 'Select C.ClientNo as ClientNo'

my query

```
Insert into [TempJobRecovery] (ClientNo,ClientName,TaxInvoiceNo,FeesforPS,TaxInvoiceDate,Partner,DeptNo,JobCode,TotalHour,TotalCost,Recovery,Status,PINO) Values
(Select C.ClientNo as ClientNo,
C.ClientName as ClientName,
C.taxinvoiceno as TaxInvoiceNo,
C.feesforps AS FeesforPS,
C.taxinvoicedte as TaxInvoiceDate,
C.Partner as Partner,
C.DeptNo as DeptNo,
C.JobCode as JobCode,
Sum(T.hrs) AS TotalHour,
Sum(T.hrs*T.corate) AS TotalCost,
(FeesforPS/TotalCost) as Recovery,
C.Status as Status,
C.PINO as PINO
 FROM Clienttaxinvoice AS C
 LEFT JOIN TimeSys AS T ON C.jobcode = T.jobcode 
WHERE ((C.ClientNo)=[T].[cntno]) and C.Taxinvoicedte>=#01/31/2017# and C.Taxinvoicedte<=#01/31/2018#GROUP BY SerialNo,ClientNo,ClientName,TaxInvoiceNo,FeesforPS,C.taxinvoicedte,Partner,DeptNo,C.JobCode,Status,PINO)
```

What is wrong with my query? Pls let me known.

Comment: Hi Loran, if you can't insert at all, then you may want to open a new question as this thread is old now.  Just use a very basic insert select query, and mention that it doesn't work.  I do think my answer fixes the problems with your actual query.

Comment: yep your answer right.I will mark as accept answer to your answer.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT INTO` when used in conjunction with a `SELECT` query does not use `VALUES`.  Rather, `VALUES` is only used with inserting literal tuples of data.  Try removing `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO [TempJobRecovery] (ClientNo, ClientName, TaxInvoiceNo, FeesforPS,
    TaxInvoiceDate, Partner, DeptNo, JobCode, TotalHour, TotalCost, Recovery,
    Status, PINO)
SELECT
    C.ClientNo,
    C.ClientName,
    C.taxinvoiceno,
    C.feesforps,
    C.taxinvoicedte,
    C.Partner,
    C.DeptNo,
    C.JobCode,
    SUM(T.hrs),
    SUM(T.hrs*T.corate),
    (FeesforPS / TotalCost),
    C.Status,
    C.PINO
FROM Clienttaxinvoice AS C
LEFT JOIN TimeSys AS T
     ON C.jobcode = T.jobcode 
WHERE
    C.ClientNo = [T].[cntno] AND
    C.Taxinvoicedte >= #01/31/2017# AND
    C.Taxinvoicedte <= #01/31/2018#
GROUP BY
    SerialNo,
    ClientNo,
    ClientName,
    TaxInvoiceNo,
    FeesforPS,
    C.taxinvoicedte,
    Partner,
    DeptNo,
    C.JobCode,
    Status,
    PINO
```

Note that I removed the aliases from the select statement above.  There is no point to use aliases, because the column names are already fixed in the destination table for the insert.

Comment: Thank for your answer,Its no error occur but its not insert to table.Why?

Comment: @Loran Without knowing/seeing your data, it is tough for me to answer that.  If the query executes without error, but nothing is inserted, then I speculate that perhaps your `WHERE` clause is filtering off all the records.  To test this, run that select statement by itself, as an independent query.  Do you get any records back?  If not, then you would know why.

Comment: Thank you for your query design,its very clean.Yep when i try with only select statement ,it return record.but when i add to insert statement ,its not working.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps the column types in the select and insert do not agree.  But in that case I would expect a formal error.  Anyway, I upvoted your question.

Comment: I already try with many dimensions, Even i created new table with one column and insert value but cant insert.

Comment: @Loran Then I suspect you have some other general problem not necessarily related to the query in your original question.

Comment: Finally i get the result but i am not sure this is a solution.After I was just writing insert query statement in code(vb) ,its work.According this experience ,if query has error,it show error message (In ms access no show error).So i make me  a little scene.Another things is , after running insert statement from code and if want to look change process in ms-access,First need to close the opening tab of table in ms-acess because of ms-access not refreshing data.

Comment: But i just copy the working query and run in ms-access it still not working. I don't understand why insert statement not working in ms-access.

Comment: @Loran I am not expert enough in Access to help further.  Someone else may be able to address your question.